# How can I setup mongo replica set with ansible?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, ansible, replicaset

I have two machines hosting one mongo instance each.

I need them to work together as a replica set.

I use Ansible for my provisioning.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Really should have been asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). But too old to migrate to there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I managed it.

I used [Stouts.mongodb](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/982) from Ansible Galaxy.

In `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- name: Provision database servers
  hosts: dbservers
  sudo: true
  vars:
    mongodb_conf_replSet=rs-name/db-hostname-1:27017,db-hostname-2:27017
    mongodb_shell:
      db-name:
        - rs.initiate()
  roles:
  - Stouts.mongodb
```

See the [mongo doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#procedure) for more details about how to set up a replica set.

Comment: Hi Raphaël,
I was also trying to do that same thing. But I don't have any `db-name` as of now. I have [this](https://gist.github.com/apanimesh061/89296f321ef835caf2c1#file-test-yml) in my playbook. I just need to get in mongo using `mongo 192.168.111.11:27017` and run `rs.initiate()`. Is this right?

Comment: I don't feel like this will work without a db-name. If you don't provide any db name when connected, the db name may be "test" or "local". Test these two or type `db.getName()` in the mongo shell. The idea behind this playbook is not to have to connect after a play.

Comment: I figured out my issue. I added this in another play. So after server restart in first play, the second initialises the replica set correctly.

Comment: The `rs.initiate()` should be run once per replica set on the **initial primary node**. If you run `rs.initiate()` from all the nodes you may risk getting the same id for several nodes. You can get the `failed with
 Received heartbeat from member with the same member ID as ourself' error that will prevent the replica from coming up.

Comment: whats ```hosts: dbservers``` what are the hosts you pass there